# XSD Validation: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"

Tags: java, xsd

I am trying to validate XML files using standard Java libraries and get the above error. My XSD file `test1.xsd` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="foo">
        <xsd:attribute name="bar" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:schema>
```

with code (running as Junit test in Eclipse):

```
@Test
public void testValidatingParser1() throws Exception {
    String SCHEMA_PATH = "test1.xsd";
    InputStream SCHEMA_STREAM = getClass().getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_PATH);
    StreamSource SCHEMA_SOURCE = new StreamSource(SCHEMA_STREAM);
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(SCHEMA_SOURCE);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setSchema(schema);
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(Unknown Source)
at org.xmlcml.graphics.misc.SchemaTest.testValidatingParser1(SchemaTest.java:123)
```

This error seems to arise from incompatibilities with XML parsers (such as Xerces) see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715023/tomcat-this-parser-does-not-support-specification-null-version-null) but I have no frameworks (other than Eclipse and Junit). I do not have xerces explicitly in my POM. Is there a simple workround (I don't mind what parser I use as long as it validates).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tracked it down to incompatible versions of Xerces, included from other software. Forcing the later versions of Xerces cures the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your XSD file is not getting accessible through `InputStream SCHEMA_STREAM = getClass().getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_PATH);`. accessible.

I validate the your code and `XSD` file with only changed line as below. It ran without any issues in `JDK 1.6` and `JDK 1.7`.

```
         InputStream SCHEMA_STREAM = new FileInputStream(new File(SCHEMA_PATH));
```

When file was not accessible, I got the `NullPointerException` little different as below:

```
        Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
          schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null'
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion but the XSD file is being read in my instance (if I edit it to be non-compliant it will fail)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in xsd?

For attributes use the attribute `use="optional"`

For elements use the attribute `nillable="true"` or use the attribute `minOccurs="0"`

[Representations of null in XML Schema](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-null/index.html)